# (Right) angle relative to line in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there an equivalent of the `tkz-euclide` command `\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed](Rx,Px) \tkzGetPoint{PRx}` in TikZ?

Comment: Perhaps you should post some MWE demonstrating what the commands you mention actually do, for people unfamiliar with `tkz-euclide`.

Comment: Do you want to draw a perpendicular line from a point on to a segment?

Comment: @Jubobs: That's the only command I do.  Given the coordinates Rx and Px, it finds a point perpendicular to that segment: PRx.

Comment: @HarishKumar, The reverse, I think: I want to find a coordinate perpendicular to line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given two coordinates named `(A)` and `(B)` you can use

```
($ (A) ! {sin(90)} ! 90:(B) $)
```

to draw a line perpendicular through `(A)` to the segment joining `(A)` and `(B)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (4,3);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\node [fill=red,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$D$] (D) at
  ($ (A) ! {sin(90)} ! 90:(B) $) {};
\draw[red] (A) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A little generalization: now the perpendicular can be drawn through any point of the segment joining the two given coordinates and can have any desired length. A command was defined:

```
\Perp[<number>]{<coord1>}{<coord2>}{<name>}[<length>]
```

`<coord1>` and `<coord1>` are the two given points and `<name>` will be used to internally label the end point of the perpendicular. `<number>` can be any real number; if `0<=<number><=1` the perpendicular will lie inside the segment (`0,5`, the default value, gives the perpendicular through the middle point). `<length>` allows control over the length of the perpendicular. For example

```
\Perp{(L)}{(M)}{T}
```

draws a perpendicular through the middle point of the segment defined by `(L)` and `(M)`; the end point of this perpendicular will be labelled `T`.

The code, including some more examples of use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\NewDocumentCommand\Perp{O{0.5}mmmO{1cm}}{%
  \coordinate (#4) at
    ($ ($ #2!#1!#3 $) ! {sin(90)} ! 90:#3 $) {};
  \draw ($ #2!#1!#3 $) -- ($ ($ #2!#1!#3 $) ! #5 ! (#4)$);
  \coordinate (#4) at ($ ($ #2!#1!#3 $) ! #5 ! (#4)$);  
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (4,3);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\Perp{(A)}{(B)}{K}

\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (C) at (5,0);
\coordinate [label=right:$D$] (D) at (7,-1);
\draw (C) -- (D);
\Perp[0.3]{(C)}{(D)}{F}[2cm]
\Perp[0.6]{(C)}{(D)}{G}[4cm]
\Perp[0.9]{(C)}{(D)}{H}[6cm]

\foreach \Nom in {K,F,G,H}
  \node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=1.5pt,label={above:$\Nom$}] at (\Nom) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution.  It might be better to have `perp` define the coordinate and let the caller draw the edge.

Comment: @NeilG I updated my answer introducing your modification.

Comment: Since sin(90)=1, why not just write 1?

Answer (score 5):

Easiest with longest code. I have `draw`n to make things visible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (p) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (q) at (3,4);
    \draw (p) -- (q) node[draw,pos=.2,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm,anchor=center,sloped] (pqn){};
    \draw[fill] (pqn.north) circle (1pt);
    \draw (pqn.center) -- (pqn.north);    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`(pqn.north)` and `(pqn.south)` are the perpendicular points at `pos=0.2`.

Answer (score 2):

A third alternative.

Use the orthogonal identifiers |- and -| for the intersections of different coordinates.  To find the intersection point C, one lets A go horizontally and B vertically. The the expression ($(A)!(C)!(B)$) yields the projection of point (C) on the line connecting (A) and (B).

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label=right:{#1}}]
\node [dot=A]  (A) at (0,0){};
\node [dot=B]  (B) at (4,3){};
\node [dot=C]  (C) at (A-|B){};
\draw (A)--(B);
\draw ($(A)!(C)!(B)$) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```